# How do I print only the output of a python curl

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this `bash` command using `python` and get the output:

This is the command I am using:

```
cmd_ = "curl -k -X GET https://consul.cicdtest.us-east-1.dev:8543/v1/kv/" +constants.NAMESPACE+"/"+constants.CONSUL_KEY+"?token="+decode_token
```

I execute above `cmd_` as below:

```
process = Popen(cmd_, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = process.stdout.read()    
print(output)
```

I get the output as follows (which is working properly):

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   144  100   144    0     0   5142      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5142

[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341651}]
```

Only output I need is:

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341651}]
```

But somehow I get this header like this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   144  100   144    0     0   5142      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5142
```

How can I remove this header like thing and access only the `Value` in the output below?

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341651}]
```

What I really want from above output is the `Value`

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have python script, you make the curl call using python. This way you can get the content of the response which is you after and better way than filtering it out from stdout. Below is python3 syntax

```
import requests

response = requests.get(f"https://consul.cicdtest.us-east-1.dev:8543/v1/kv/{constants.NAMESPACE}/{constants.CONSUL_KEY}?token={decode_token}")
print(response.content)
```

Below is python2.7 syntax

```
import requests
url =  "https://consul.cicdtest.us-east-1.dev:8543/v1/kv/" +constants.NAMESPACE+"/"+constants.CONSUL_KEY+"?token="+decode_token
response = requests.get(url)
print response.content
```

Comment: Good suggestion -- using a Python library instead of the cURL CLI is far better. Technically this is not a `cURL` call as `requests` uses Python's `urllib` to do the HTTP request

Comment: I am using python `2.7`, how can I use this approach for python `2.7`?

Answer (score 1):

`curl -s` makes Curl silent.

> `-s`, `--silent` Silent or quiet mode.
>   Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

However, the actual problem here is you're setting `stderr=STDOUT`, so the progress meter, usually printed to the standard error stream, is redirected to the standard output stream you're capturing.

You'll also want to get rid of that.

Comment: This approach is really working. How can I filter out only the value of `Value` from my `json` output?